# is beanstalk plugin deploy nothing to aws elb?

Tags: java, maven, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy my war file to aws elb. In logs I can see that:

- war file uploaded to s3
- new application created
- elb environment replaced

but in aws log I can't see any actions from my application...

pom.xml:

```
   <plugin>
        <groupId>br.com.ingenieux</groupId>
        <artifactId>beanstalk-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5</version>
        <configuration>
            <environmentName>my</environmentName>
            <cnamePrefix>my</cnamePrefix>
            <s3Bucket>archive-for-elb</s3Bucket>
            <s3Key>${project.build.finalName}-${maven.build.timestamp}.war</s3Key>
            <artifactFile>target/my.war</artifactFile>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

maven log:

```
[INFO]
[INFO] --- beanstalk-maven-plugin:1.3.5:upload-source-bundle (default-cli) @ my ---
[INFO] Target Path: s3://archive-for-elb/my-0.1.0-2014-10-23T22:21:21Z.war
[INFO] Uploading artifact file: .../my.war
  100.00% 29 MiB/29 MiB                        Done
[INFO] Artifact Uploaded
[INFO] SUCCESS
[INFO]
[INFO] --- beanstalk-maven-plugin:1.3.5:create-application-version (default-cli) @ my ---
[INFO] SUCCESS
[INFO]  * dateCreated: Fri Oct 24 01:21:39 FET 2014 [class: Date]
[INFO]  * sourceBundle: {S3Bucket: archive-for-elb,S3Key: my-0.1.0-2014-10-23T22:21:21Z.war} [class: S3Location]
[INFO]  * versionLabel: 0.1.0 [class: String]
[INFO]  * description: Update from beanstalk-maven-plugin [class: String]
[INFO]  * applicationName: my [class: String]
[INFO]  * dateUpdated: Fri Oct 24 01:21:39 FET 2014 [class: Date]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- beanstalk-maven-plugin:1.3.5:replace-environment (default-cli) @ my ---
[INFO] Creating a new environment on my-0.elasticbeanstalk.com
[INFO] Excluding Option Setting: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:AWS_SECRET_KEY['']
[INFO] Excluding Option Setting: aws:cloudformation:template:parameter:AppSource['http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/elasticbeanstalk-samples-eu-west-1/elasticbeanstalk-sampleapp.war']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:tomcat:jvmoptions:Xmx['1024m']
[INFO] Excluding Option Setting: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID['']
[INFO] Excluding Option Setting: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:tomcat:jvmoptions:JVM Options['']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:cloudformation:template:parameter:JVMOptions['JVM Options=,XX:MaxPermSize=128m,Xmx=1024m,Xms=512m']
[INFO] Excluding Option Setting: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:PARAM1['']
[INFO] Excluding Option Setting: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:PARAM2['']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:cloudformation:template:parameter:InstancePort['80']
[INFO] Excluding Option Setting: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:PARAM4['']
[INFO] Excluding Option Setting: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:PARAM3['']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:cloudformation:template:parameter:EnvironmentVariables['PARAM3=,PARAM4=,PARAM1=,PARAM2=,JDBC_CONNECTION_STRING=,AWS_SECRET_KEY=,PARAM5=,AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=']
[INFO] Excluding Option Setting: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:PARAM5['']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:elasticbeanstalk:hostmanager:LogPublicationControl['false']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:tomcat:jvmoptions:XX:MaxPermSize['128m']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:tomcat:jvmoptions:Xms['512m']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:InstanceType['m1.small']
[INFO] Excluding Option Setting: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:JDBC_CONNECTION_STRING['']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:elb:loadbalancer:CrossZone['false']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:elb:healthcheck:Interval['30']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:elb:loadbalancer:LoadBalancerHTTPSPort['OFF']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:elb:healthcheck:Timeout['5']
[INFO] Excluding Option Setting: aws:elb:loadbalancer:SSLCertificateId['']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:elb:healthcheck:UnhealthyThreshold['5']
[INFO] Excluding Option Setting: aws:ec2:vpc:ELBSubnets['']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:elb:policies:Stickiness Policy['false']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:elb:policies:ConnectionDrainingTimeout['20']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:elb:loadbalancer:LoadBalancerPortProtocol['HTTP']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:elb:loadbalancer:LoadBalancerSSLPortProtocol['HTTPS']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:elb:healthcheck:Target['TCP:80']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:elb:policies:Stickiness Cookie Expiration['0']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:elb:healthcheck:HealthyThreshold['3']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:elb:policies:ConnectionDrainingEnabled['false']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:ec2:vpc:ELBScheme['public']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:elb:loadbalancer:LoadBalancerHTTPPort['80']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:ImageId['ami-937474e7']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:MonitoringInterval['5 minute']
[INFO] Excluding Option Setting: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:SecurityGroups['awseb-e-5dguwgvhms-stack-AWSEBSecurityGroup-16ADZATAGHYA2']
[INFO] Excluding Option Setting: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:RootVolumeType['']
[INFO] Excluding Option Setting: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:IamInstanceProfile['']
[INFO] Excluding Option Setting: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:RootVolumeSize['']
[INFO] Excluding Option Setting: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:BlockDeviceMappings['']
[INFO] Excluding Option Setting: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:EC2KeyName['']
[INFO] Excluding Option Setting: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:RootVolumeIOPS['']
[INFO] Excluding Option Setting: aws:ec2:vpc:AssociatePublicIpAddress['']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:autoscaling:asg:MaxSize['4']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:autoscaling:asg:Cooldown['360']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:autoscaling:asg:MinSize['1']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:autoscaling:asg:Availability Zones['Any']
[INFO] Excluding Option Setting: aws:autoscaling:updatepolicy:rollingupdate:MinInstancesInService['']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:autoscaling:updatepolicy:rollingupdate:RollingUpdateEnabled['false']
[INFO] Excluding Option Setting: aws:autoscaling:asg:Custom Availability Zones['']
[INFO] Excluding Option Setting: aws:ec2:vpc:Subnets['']
[INFO] Excluding Option Setting: aws:autoscaling:updatepolicy:rollingupdate:MaxBatchSize['']
[INFO] Excluding Option Setting: aws:autoscaling:updatepolicy:rollingupdate:PauseTime['']
[INFO] Excluding Option Setting: aws:ec2:vpc:VPCId['']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:autoscaling:trigger:UpperThreshold['6000000']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:autoscaling:trigger:Period['5']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:autoscaling:trigger:Statistic['Average']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:autoscaling:trigger:MeasureName['NetworkOut']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:autoscaling:trigger:LowerThreshold['2000000']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:autoscaling:trigger:EvaluationPeriods['1']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:autoscaling:trigger:Unit['Bytes']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:autoscaling:trigger:BreachDuration['5']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:autoscaling:trigger:LowerBreachScaleIncrement['-1']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:autoscaling:trigger:UpperBreachScaleIncrement['1']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:elasticbeanstalk:control:RollbackLaunchOnFailure['false']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:elasticbeanstalk:control:DefaultSSHPort['22']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:elasticbeanstalk:control:LaunchType['Migration']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:elasticbeanstalk:monitoring:Automatically Terminate Unhealthy Instances['true']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:elasticbeanstalk:control:LaunchTimeout['0']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:EnvironmentType['LoadBalanced']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:SSHSourceRestriction['tcp,22,22,0.0.0.0/0']
[INFO] Excluding Option Setting: aws:elasticbeanstalk:sns:topics:Notification Topic ARN['']
[INFO] Excluding Option Setting: aws:elasticbeanstalk:sns:topics:Notification Endpoint['']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:elasticbeanstalk:command:BatchSize['100']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:elasticbeanstalk:command:Timeout['600']
[INFO] Excluding Option Setting: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:Application Healthcheck URL['']
[INFO] Excluding Option Setting: aws:elasticbeanstalk:sns:topics:Notification Topic Name['']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:elasticbeanstalk:sns:topics:Notification Protocol['email']
[INFO] Including Option Setting: aws:elasticbeanstalk:command:BatchSizeType['Percentage']
[INFO] And it'll be named my-0
[INFO] Using latest available application version 0.1.0
[INFO] Environment Lookup
[INFO] ... with environmentId equal to 'e-wt6wzxjpyj'
[INFO] ... with status   set to 'Ready'
[INFO] ... with health equal to 'Green'
[INFO] INFO Fri Oct 24 01:21:48 FET 2014 Using elasticbeanstalk-eu-west-1-896684893807 as Amazon S3 storage bucket for environment data.
[INFO] INFO Fri Oct 24 01:22:02 FET 2014 Created load balancer named: awseb-e-w-AWSEBLoa-WS5L7G9XB5XU
[INFO] INFO Fri Oct 24 01:22:23 FET 2014 Created security group named: awseb-e-wt6wzxjpyj-stack-AWSEBSecurityGroup-UT0K8K743BWJ
[INFO] INFO Fri Oct 24 01:22:26 FET 2014 Created Auto Scaling launch configuration named: awseb-e-wt6wzxjpyj-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingLaunchConfiguration-ONMFRQKQFVF1
[INFO] INFO Fri Oct 24 01:23:24 FET 2014 Created Auto Scaling group named: awseb-e-wt6wzxjpyj-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-1GLBECAPXKOWG
[INFO] INFO Fri Oct 24 01:23:28 FET 2014 Created Auto Scaling group policy named: arn:aws:autoscaling:eu-west-1:896684893807:scalingPolicy:315fb3b8-e461-441d-8d8d-5aa9e9e09f40:autoScalingGroupName/awseb-e-wt6wzxjpyj-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-1GLBECAPXKOWG:policyName/awseb-e-wt6wzxjpyj-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingScaleUpPolicy-IUQ473KRVY73
[INFO] INFO Fri Oct 24 01:23:28 FET 2014 Created Auto Scaling group policy named: arn:aws:autoscaling:eu-west-1:896684893807:scalingPolicy:96912dc4-b9ac-4c47-9d76-99ef4087600e:autoScalingGroupName/awseb-e-wt6wzxjpyj-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-1GLBECAPXKOWG:policyName/awseb-e-wt6wzxjpyj-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingScaleDownPolicy-1HPVBP4235CI2
[INFO] INFO Fri Oct 24 01:23:31 FET 2014 Created CloudWatch alarm named: awseb-e-wt6wzxjpyj-stack-AWSEBCloudwatchAlarmHigh-1B5FQS201RIN7
[INFO] INFO Fri Oct 24 01:23:32 FET 2014 Created CloudWatch alarm named: awseb-e-wt6wzxjpyj-stack-AWSEBCloudwatchAlarmLow-V2IM7CXM1XR0
[INFO] Waiting for environmentId e-wt6wzxjpyj to get into Ready state
[INFO] Environment Lookup
[INFO] ... with environmentId equal to 'e-wt6wzxjpyj'
[INFO] ... with status   set to 'Ready'
[INFO] ... with health equal to 'Green'
[INFO] Swapping environment cnames e-wt6wzxjpyj and e-5dguwgvhms
[INFO] Skipping r53 domain binding
[INFO] Environment Lookup
[INFO] ... with environmentId equal to 'e-wt6wzxjpyj'
[INFO] ... with status   set to 'Ready'
[INFO] Terminating environmentId=e-5dguwgvhms (attempt 1/15)
[INFO] SUCCESS
[INFO]  * solutionStackName: 32bit Amazon Linux running Tomcat 7 [class: String]
[INFO]  * description: my [class: String]
[INFO]  * health: Grey [class: String]
[INFO]  * dateUpdated: Fri Oct 24 01:21:44 FET 2014 [class: Date]
[INFO]  * dateCreated: Fri Oct 24 01:21:44 FET 2014 [class: Date]
[INFO]  * environmentId: e-wt6wzxjpyj [class: String]
[INFO]  * versionLabel: 0.1.0 [class: String]
[INFO]  * tier: {Name: WebServer,Type: Standard,Version: 1.0} [class: EnvironmentTier]
[INFO]  * environmentName: my-0 [class: String]
[INFO]  * CNAME: my-0.elasticbeanstalk.com [class: String]
[INFO]  * applicationName: my [class: String]
[INFO]  * status: Launching [class: String]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

catalina.out from aws:

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out
-------------------------------------
tomcat7-7.0.27 RPM installed
Oct 23, 2014 10:25:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0/jre/lib/i386/client:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0/jre/lib/i386:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0/jre/../lib/i386:/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/lib:/usr/lib
Oct 23, 2014 10:25:49 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Oct 23, 2014 10:25:49 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Oct 23, 2014 10:25:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1507 ms
Oct 23, 2014 10:25:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Oct 23, 2014 10:25:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.27
Oct 23, 2014 10:25:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT
Oct 23, 2014 10:26:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Oct 23, 2014 10:26:04 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Oct 23, 2014 10:26:04 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Oct 23, 2014 10:26:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 14683 ms
```

**UPD1**

```
<properties>
    <beanstalker.region>eu-west-1</beanstalker.region>
</properties>
```

**UPD2**

I got access to the instance via ssh and I found deployed application in /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT as described in log. 
I dowloaded the same version of tomcat and tried to deploy in the same folder the same war (i downloaded war from aws) as in aws - everything is fine and application started...

Any ideas why it is not started in aws tomcat?

Comment: another thing - what do you mean by 'aws log'? AWS Console or "Fetch Snapshot logs" output?

Comment: @aldrinleal i mean Logs -> Request logs -> Download

Comment: So its no longer a maven plugin problem, but Tomcat and AWS :) - There's a quite lengthy discussion on logging on AWS Elastic Beanstalk on the AWS forums, and I suggest you look there. Usual suspects include classpath hell and the way AWS Patches tomcat (hint: look under /var/log/eb-*)

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm the Availability Zone from the AWS Console?

By default, beanstalker uses us-east-1, but for new AWS Accounts, the default tends to be us-west-1 instead

Comment: Configuration -> Instances -> "Availability Zones: Any"

Comment: ec2 instance has "availability zone: eu-west-1c"

Answer (score 0):

The key is:

```
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
```

The answer is very simple: in the aws instance was installed jdk6 but code was compiled with jdk7.
It is very strange that it is not any extra messages about it.

Also there is no any info about installed jdk in case of installed jdk6.
"Configuration" section contains label "32bit Amazon Linux running Tomcat 7" only.
But when I created new environment with jdk7 label changed to "64bit Amazon Linux 2014.09 v1.0.9 running Tomcat 7 Java 7"...